# Ubuntu Studio 17 stuck at the spinny logo on boot

Tags: ubuntu

I'm stuck on boot with the spinny Ubuntu logo never stopping.

I just started a new job and was given an existing HP with Ubuntu Studio 17 on it.  I was rolling along on it just fine until I decided I wanted to try out the Sublime Text editor, which requires the root user, which the machine wasn't set up for.

I had some success getting root enabled, but it still wasn't allowing me to get Sublime installed, so I looked around for some more hints, and The Last Thing I did was follow these instructions: http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/enable-ubuntu-desktop-root-login/

... which ends with editing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

...saved that and rebooted.  Can't get past the spinny ubuntu start up screen now.

I finally booted from a Live CD and edited the above changes out, but the computer is still stuck in spinny logo purgatory.

What the heck do I do now?

Comment: read the logfiles.

Comment: Ah yes, but *which* logs?

Comment: all of them....